# How can I achieve something like this image with chart.js(react-chartjs-2)?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this -

1. Different colour in the same bar
2. Color length proportional to % of data available in that year

In total there are 4 years and I want to partition each bar into a maximum of 4 parts (can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 parts depending on years selected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is something called "Stacked Bar Chart". This kind of chart can be used with the library you mentioned.

As in the documentation:

> Stacked bar charts can be used to show how one data series is made up of a number of smaller pieces.

Here an example taken from the documentation:

```
var stackedBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please, for more details refer to this section of the documentation:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/charts/bar/#stacked-bar-chart

Comment: Appreciate the quick response, it helps a lot.